Copy file from azure blob storage to sftp server
I have a azure blob storage file. Can I use a SFTP client to copy the file from azure blob storage into another SFTP server?
That is provision in azure block storage to connect to it using SFTP client. If I run the client in my Java application, I would be able to transfer files from azure blob storage to where the client runs. but I want the file in another sftp server. Is it possible to do this and in one step?

Yes you can.
What you need to do is enable SFTP on your blob storage, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/secure-file-transfer-protocol-support
However, the SFTP service has a cost, and your Java client could assess the blob storage directly.
